# Creating C# Objects Dynamically

Tags: c#, json

Currently having an issue creating a reusable object that I will need to use in a JSON construct string function.

Currently I have the following to create the bulk of the JSON string:

```
var data = new
  {
    record = new
      {
        value1 = Row.value1,
        value2 = Row.value2,
        form_values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
       }
   };
data.record.form_values["833b"] = Row.value3.ToString();
data.record.form_values["98wq"] = BuildMultiSelectList(Row.value3.ToString()); 



public object BuildMultiSelectList(string datavalue)
{
    var choicelist = new { 
                      choice_values: [datavalue],
                      other_values: [],
                      };
    return choicelist;
}
```

The top half all works fine, though the function BuildMultiSelectList is giving errors such as "choice_values" does not exist in the current context and datavalue does not exist in the current context.

Any insight on why this has gone a bit rouge will be appreciated.

Comment: `choice_values: [datavalue], other_values: [],` isn't valid C#. Use the conventional [anonymous type syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) as you did in the first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are just mixing colon `:` with `=`?

```
        var choicelist = new { 
                      choice_values = new string[] {datavalue},
                      other_values = new[] {},
                      };
```

Comment: I have been known to be a bit simple sometimes... Embarrassing miss I think its bed time!